# Cannot install opencv4nodejs using npm i -g opencv4nodejs on Mac OS 12.1 with Intel

Tags: opencv, node-modules, appium-ios

ARN AppiumDoctor  ➜ Why opencv4nodejs is needed and how to install it: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/image-comparison.md

When I ran Appium doctor - I got the output above.

When I try to install - the error is: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/install/install.js:37
npm ERR!   throw new Error('library dir does not exist: ' + libDir)
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: library dir does not exist: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/node_modules/opencv-build/opencv/build/lib
npm ERR!     at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/install/install.js:37:9)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Node.js v17.4.0

My node version is 17.4.0; I have tried switching to version 14 and that did not work.
I have also uninstalled node an reinstalled - that did not work. The same was done for npm. How can I get this installed? Is it still needed to automate my tests on the simulator?

Comment: what exactly is the error? `Cannot install opencv4nodejs`? does it give any other details?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I updated the question w/ the error.

Comment: there is a clone, https://www.npmjs.com/package/@u4/opencv-build  and a related issue https://github.com/UrielCh/opencv4nodejs/issues/16 . Can you try it?